# How do I redefine a color pair in ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

The title should say it all, so say I created a color pair like this:

```
init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
```

And then I wanted to redefine it, like this:

```
init_pair(1, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLUE);
```

Now this doesn't work, but are there any other functions that allow me to do so? Or heck, are there functions so that I can just use explicit foreground/background colors without using color pairs?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if this isn't clear enough.

---

**EDIT**: After trying it out, you *can* redefine pairs using `init_pair`, and the problem in my code was somewhere else.

Comment: Just a note: if the color-pair was previously initialized, the screen is refreshed and all occurrences of that color-pair are changed to the new definition. So you cannot use just one color pair all the time, since any change will affect the previous drawings as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can define up to 7 color pairs at a time and show them all in sequence if you like. You just CHANGE the number and refresh. for example. (we'll do it with 3) see [here](http://snap.nlc.dcccd.edu/learn/fuller3/chap6/chap6.html) for an e printout of an example with 7

```
 #include  <curses.h>

 int COLOR_PAIR (int PAIR_NUMBER)

 init_pair(1, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_RED);
 init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLUE);
 init_pair(3, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLUE);

 for (i=1, i <=3, i++){
   attroffset(A_BOLD)
   attrset(COLOR_PAIR(i))
   refresh();
   sleep(1);
}
```

note if you have a lot of pairs and the second colour is always the same or the first one is unique in each pair, you can turn it on using attron()  e.g. attron(COLOR_PAIR(COLOR_BLUE)); (this wouldn't work in our definitions)

you can view an example of attron [here](http://www.roguetemple.com/forums/index.php?topic=319.0;wap2)

Comment: So there is no way of editing a color pair once it is created?

Comment: you can try can_change_colour() but most terminals don't handle that very well

Comment: Thanks for the information, I have found the answer to my problem, which was not related to this question (apparently you _can_ redefine color pairs, the bug was somewhere else).

Comment: Please post how,  its an faq!

Comment: 'You can define up to 7 color pairs at a time'. This is not necessarily true. In my xterm-256color I can define at least 256 colorpairs.

Comment: More precisely, in my xterm-256color, the constant `curses.COLORPAIRS` contains the number 32767.